# Solaris 5.10 telnet connection closed by foreign host

Tags: networking, solaris, telnet, solaris-10

I try to connect to a Solaris 5.10 server using telnet, but I only see:

```
$ telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The server don't run TCP Wrappers.

Here is the server configuration:

```
bash-3.00# svcs -l telnet
fmri         svc:/network/telnet:default
name         Telnet server
enabled      true
state        online
next_state   none
state_time   Thu Jul 23 19:14:57 2015
restarter    svc:/network/inetd:default
contract_id

bash-3.00# svcs -l inetd
fmri         svc:/network/inetd:default
name         inetd
enabled      true
state        online
next_state   none
state_time   Thu Jul 23 19:14:52 2015
logfile      /var/svc/log/network-inetd:default.log
restarter    svc:/system/svc/restarter:default
contract_id  2982586
dependency   require_any/error svc:/network/loopback (online)
dependency   require_all/error svc:/system/filesystem/local (online)
dependency   optional_all/error svc:/milestone/network (online)
dependency   optional_all/error svc:/network/rpc/bind (online)
dependency   optional_all/none svc:/network/inetd-upgrade (disabled)
dependency   require_all/none svc:/milestone/sysconfig (online) svc:/milestone/name-services (online)

bash-3.00# inetadm -l telnet
SCOPE    NAME=VALUE
         name="telnet"
         endpoint_type="stream"
         proto="tcp6"
         isrpc=FALSE
         wait=FALSE
         exec="/usr/sbin/in.telnetd"
         user="root"
default  bind_addr=""
default  bind_fail_max=-1
default  bind_fail_interval=-1
default  max_con_rate=-1
default  max_copies=-1
default  con_rate_offline=-1
default  failrate_cnt=40
default  failrate_interval=60
default  inherit_env=TRUE
default  tcp_trace=FALSE
default  tcp_wrappers=FALSE
```

The port 23 is open in the server OK, I test it using nmap:

```
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
```

I tried conect from localhost, but I get the same result:

```
bash-3.00# telnet localhost
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection to localhost closed by foreign host.
```

I also compare the server configuration with others that run fine, and everything I see are the same, I run out of ideas.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you have a firewall on this box?

Comment: @TimS. No, no firewall. Also client and server are in the same local network.

Comment: anything interesting in the `/var/svc/log/network-inetd`? `proto="tcp6"` is ciruous -- what happens when you connect to `::1` instead?